# determining the end of asynchronous operations javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

If I have a function that's passed this function:

```
function(work) {
   work(10);
   work(20);
   work(30);
}
```

(There can be any number of `work` calls with any number in them.)

`work` performance some asynchronous activity—say, for this example, it just is a `timeout`. I have full control over what `work` does on the completion of this operation (and, in fact, its definition in general).

What's the best way of determining when all the calls to `work` are done?

---

My current method increments a counter when work is called and decrements it when it completes, and fires the `all work done` event when the counter is 0 (this is checked after every decrement). However, I worry that this could be a race condition of some sort. If that is not the case, do show my why and that would be a great answer.

Comment: this is something to consider, at least the principle: http://www.benjiegillam.com/2011/11/multiple-asynchronous-callbacks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of ways you can write this program, but your simple technique of using a counter will work just fine.

The important thing to remember, the reason this will work, is because **Javascript executes in a single thread**. This is true of all browsers and node.js AFAIK.

Based on the thoughtful comments below, the solution works because the JS event loop will execute the functions in an order like:

1. function(work)
2. work(10)
3. counter++
4. Start async function
5. work(20)
6. counter++
7. Start async function
8. work(30)
9. counter++
10. Start async function
11. -- back out to event loop --
12. Async function completes
13. counter--
14. -- back out to event loop --
15. Async function completes
16. counter--
17. -- back out to event loop --
18. Async function completes
19. counter--
20. Counter is 0, so you fire your work done message
21. -- back out to event loop --

Comment: Why does the single thread mean that this would work? What's wrong with a counter in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @davin counter might hit local minima of `0` before all the work is finished. I.e. doWork(1), doWork(2), < both finished, counter is 0 fire callback> doWork(3)

Comment: You would have to guarantee that your counter was being updated atomically if it was being accessed by multiple threads. In some languages i++ or i-- is not guaranteed to be atomic because the operation involves both reading a variable and setting it. This puts it at the mercy of the thread scheduler in a multi-threaded environment. There may be other considerations around multiple threads running at once depending on your use case-- such as the one @Raynos pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, if js was multi-threaded presumably there would be concurrency control to make this safe. By the way js is single-threaded by standard definitions, not just implementation based.

Comment: Additionally, I believe the nature of Javascript execution lends itself to this case. If work() first increments a counter and then does something asynchronously, I think the asynchronous operations won't return until the next time the event loop runs, so each work() function is executed, loses control when it calls an async operation, then moves to the next work() in your function. The counter only gets incremented in the first pass, then as each work() finishes, the counters get decremented. I'm not sure if this is assuming too much about the operation of the JS interpreter or not.

Comment: That's exactly how it works, which is what Raynos' comment is based on.

Comment: Cool, I was pretty sure JS doesn't interrupt the flow of control... it just waits for the next iteration of the event loop. Obviously, this solution would be a train wreck in multithreaded languages for several reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There's no race condition. There is the added requirement for every request made to perform a decrement when it's finished (*always!* including on http failure, which is easy to forget). But that can be handled in a more encapsulated way by wrapping you calls.

Untested, but this is the gist (I've implemented an object instead of a counter, so theoretically you can extend this to have more granular queries about specific requests):

```
var ajaxWrapper = (function() {
   var id = 0, calls = {};
   return {
      makeRequest: function() {
         $.post.apply($, arguments); // for example
         calls[id] = true;
         return id++;
      },
      finishRequest: function(id) {
         delete calls[id];
      },
      isAllDone: function(){
         var prop;
         for(prop in calls) {
            if(calls.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {return false;}
         }
         return true;
      }
   };
})();
```

Usage:

Instead of `$.post("url", ... function(){ /*success*/ } ... );` We'll do

```
var requestId;
requestId = ajaxWrapper.makeRequest("url", ...
   function(){ /*success*/ ajaxWrapper.finishRequest(requestId); } ... );
```

If you wanted to be even more sophisticated you could add the calls to `finishRequest` yourself inside the wrapper, so usage would be almost entirely transparent:

```
 ajaxWrapper.makeRequest("url", ... function(){ /*success*/ } ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an `after` utility function.

```
var after = function _after(count, f) {
  var c = 0, results = [];
  return function _callback() {
    switch (arguments.length) {
      case 0: results.push(null); break;
      case 1: results.push(arguments[0]); break;
      default: results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); break;
    }
    if (++c === count) {
      f.apply(this, results);
    }
  };
};
```

The following code below would just work. Because javascript is single threaded.

```
function doWork(work) {
  work(10);
  work(20);
  work(30);
}

WorkHandler(doWork);

function WorkHandler(cb) {
  var counter = 0,
      finish;
  cb(function _work(item) {
    counter++;
    // somethingAsync calls `finish` when it's finished
    somethingAsync(item, function _cb() {
      finish()
    });
  });
  finish = after(counter, function() {
    console.log('work finished');
  });
};
```

I guess I should explain.

We pass the function that does work to the workhandler.

The work handler calls it and passes in work.

The function that does work calls work multiple times incrementing the counter

Since the function that does work is not asynchronous (very important) we can define the finish function after it has finished.

The asynchronouswork that is being done cannot finish (and call the undefined finish function) before the current synchronous block of work (the execution of the entire workhandler) has finished.

This means that after the entire workhandler has finished (and the variable finish is set) the asynchronous work jobs will start to end and call finish. Only once all of them have called finish will the callback send to `after` fire.